# Getting ID of current user into the URL of a method in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

What I want to do is having the ID of the current user into the url parameter for my Express patch method.
Is it even possible to do this? I could get the ID from the Axios request but it cannot be passed without using a method. Hope anyone could enlighten me on this issue.

```
app.patch(`/users/edit/{id-of-the-user}`, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `req.params`.
Refer to [Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

```
app.patch(`/users/edit/:userId`, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.userId);
});
```